# Update sql query with laravel

Tags: php, sql, ajax, laravel

I'm quite new in laravel and I would like to update a data in my database.
But I don't really know why I got an `error 500`.
Could you tell me if there is something wrong with my code ?

```
if (status === 1) {
                url = "{{ route('bannerLocation.disable') }}";
                requestData.offerId = 23;
                // Handle offer action
                // You need to implement the logic here for making API calls
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    url: url,
                    data: requestData,
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        $('.bannersController-datatable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log(xhr, status, error);
                    }
   });
}
```

Controller.php:

```
public function disable(Request $request)
    {
        $offerId = $request->input('offerId');

        BannersLocation::where(['id' => $offerId])->update(['status' => 2]);
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Offer status updated successfully']);
    }
```

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message. For Laravel, check in `storage/logs`

Comment: I already checked there is nothing about this query in my logs

Comment: Check you error logs and share the error message.

Comment: Are you sure it's the query itself? The 500 error might be from something else, and that should be in the logs. If you are in your dev environment, set `APP_DEBUG=true` in your .env and then check the network response in your browser's developer tools

Comment: not really. And i'm in prod environment

Comment: BannersLocation::where(['id' => $offerId])->update(['status' => 2]); Is this correct? 

It should be like this -  BannersLocation::where('id', $offerId)->update(['status' => 2]);

Comment: @MohammedJhosawa I always have the same issue with this.

Comment: Can you check server error logs - /var/logs/apache2/error.log

Comment: You need to look into what the error is. Search for errors in the server logs and look into stack traces and exception messages to find out what and where was the problem. If the query was being sent to the database at all, then you might also want to check your database logs as well and see whether this update has been executed and if so whether it was successful.

Comment: Ok mb I'm downloading logs from the server but 1M lines it will take few minutes

Comment: you don't need to download the logs. You can open them with vim and search for the exception.

Comment: `tail` would also work, since it should be at the bottom of the file. You can add a number qualifier if it's adding the trace and it's too long. `tail -n 50 filename`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using :

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

In laravel when we make an update query, the program make an update on `your_table.updated_at` but if you don't have this column on your table you have to put this parameters on your table model.